# Will Windows 8.1 upgrade key work with new install

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-8.1-upgrade

After I upgrade to windows 8.1 from Microsoft store, if I retrieved the key using any key finding tools, will it be a new key, and will it work with new installation of windows 8.1?

Answer (score 0):

yes the key will work, but you need to do some hacks.

You must install Windows 8.1 from a clean 8.1 ISO with a generic key, insert your key and apply the [old MediaBootInstall trick from Windows 7](http://winsupersite.com/article/windows-7/clean-install-windows-7-with-upgrade-media-128512).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I upgraded from Windows 8 to 8.1, but after Upgrade when I check the key, it was exactly the same as windows 8 key, which is never going to work with Windows 8.

Comment: Also Windows 8.1 doesn't provide an Upgrade media, I think

Comment: yes, the upgrade uses the old Win8 key. This key can't be use to do a clean install with a 8.1 ISO. You can install Win8 again and do the store update again. This will also work, but takes more time.